# GridSearchCV fit takes 19 times longer than the base classifier even when there's only one possible set of params

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, gridsearchcv

I have written a simple benchmark that shows that using the GridSearchCV fit function in scikit-learn with the base classifier as LogisticRegression and only one set of possible hyperparameters takes at least 8 times and up to 19 times longer than just using the fit function of the base classifier. Any idea why this big difference is happening? Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, GridSearchCV

iris = load_iris()
logistic = LogisticRegression(solver='saga', tol=1e-2, max_iter=200,
                              random_state=0, n_jobs=36)
distributions = dict(C=[1], penalty=['l1'])

ls = [next(ShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=.25, random_state=0).split(iris.data))]
train_X = iris.data[ls[0][0]]
train_Y = iris.target[ls[0][0]]

n = 20
tot_t = 0
for _ in range(n):
    t0 = time.time()
    clf = GridSearchCV(logistic, distributions, n_jobs=36, cv=ls)
    search = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
    tot_t += time.time() - t0
print(f"avg = {tot_t / n}")

tot_t = 0
for _ in range(n):
    t0 = time.time()
    clf = logistic
    search = clf.fit(train_X, train_Y)
    tot_t += time.time() - t0
print(f"avg = {tot_t / n}")
```

The results for clf = logistic, and clf = GSCV are 0.324 and 0.017, respectively (19 times slower). Note that for GSCV, there's only one set of hyperparams possible (C=1, penalty='l1'), so basically, GSCV has to fit only one clf and not multiple, and there's no CV (only one set of splits is given to it), yet it's taking much more time!

If I make iris.data and itis.target 100 times larger:

```
iris.data = np.repeat(iris.data, 100, axis=0)
iris.target = np.repeat(iris.target, 100, axis=0)
```

I get these results: 0.528 and 0.064 (8 times slower).
With 1000 times larger iris.data and iris.target: 2.70 and 0.34 (8 times slower).

I tested with the normal iris.data and iris.target with RandomizedCV:

```
clf = RandomizedSearchCV(logistic, distributions, random_state=2, n_jobs=36, cv=ls)
```

and got these results: 0.337 and 0.013 (26 times slower).

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are calling 36 threads for the logistic regression part, and then on top of this, trying to parallelize this in GridSearchCV with `n_jobs=36` . This is parallelizing twice and might slow down your processes.

For logistic regression, parallel only works if you have multi class, as from the documentation:

```
n_jobs int, default=None
Number of CPU cores used when parallelizing over classes if multi_class=’ovr’”.
```

If you have 2 or 3 classes, like in iris, it doesn't quite matter, so you can do:

```
logistic = LogisticRegression(solver='saga', tol=1e-2, max_iter=200,random_state=0, n_jobs=None)
```

GridSearchCV does more than fitting the model, it calculates the score of the model, and also summarizes it across. So you need to set `refit = False` to ensure it doesn't refit the best model on the full dataset. Also in this example, setting cv=None ensures it doesn't run parallel processes. We can also include a test dataset so that we perform the scoring as well:

```
test_X = iris.data[ls[0][1]]
test_Y = iris.target[ls[0][1]]
```

For example if I do :

```
n = 20
tot_t = 0
for _ in range(n):
    t0 = time.time()
    clf = GridSearchCV(logistic, distributions, n_jobs=None, cv=ls, refit = False)
    search = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
    tot_t += time.time() - t0
print(f"avg = {tot_t / n}")

tot_t = 0
for _ in range(n):
    t0 = time.time()
    clf = logistic
    search = clf.fit(train_X, train_Y)
    score_test = clf.score(test_X,test_Y)
    tot_t += time.time() - t0
print(f"avg = {tot_t / n}")
```

I get:

```
avg = 0.0036052584648132322
avg = 0.0019430875778198241
```

So the difference is not so huge, once you account for the other calculations made by GridSearchCV.

In your case, I believe your `GridSearchCV` is caused by calling n_job = 36 in both `logisticRegression` and `GridSearchCV` . Most likely you only want to call it once with `GridSearchCV`, in the case of testing many hyperparameters.

Comment: Thanks! I realized where the problem was. Changing n_jobs to 1 in LR didn't have a substantial impact. However, changing n_jobs in GSCV did when I made it 1. Apparently, GridSearchCV creates n_jobs threads no matter it needs/uses them or not! In this case, even though it needs and uses one thread, it creates 36 threads!

Comment: The same thing happens in LR as well. It creates more than what it needs. I did n_jobs=36 in LR and n_jobs=1 in GSCV and got the same results. However, it's interesting that setting both of them to 36 does not degrade the performance that much w.r.t when one of them is 36 and the other one is 1.

Comment: You should set it to None. Setting it to 1 calls joblib whereas None would just run the single process

Comment: @StupidWolf do you have a reference for that last comment?